# Random TimeOuts in vb.NET Thread Code (Task Factory)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, timeout

I am working with a big application. It starts at the beggining of the form declaring and starting some threads:

```
      Thread1 = New Thread(AddressOf Thread1Sub)
      Thread1.Start()

      Thread2= New Thread(AddressOf Thread2Sub)
      Thread2.Start()
```

Ok. The program can be running without a problem for several minutes, hours, days. But then
randomly we start getting  an exception performing trivial database jobs like getting one registry.

I doubt that the GetRegistry database operation is faulty because it can be executed a thousand times, even more before I start getting the timeoutException.

Since this hangs started, I changed the  problematic function call and I am currently starting a new task as follows:

```
Dim TokenCancel As New CancellationTokenSource
Dim taskConta = Tasks.Task(Of DataSet).Factory.StartNew(                                             
Function() myFunc(param1, param2),
     TokenCancel.Token, Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)

If taskConta.Wait(ThreadTimeOut) Then
 datos = taskConta.Result
Else
 Throw New TimeoutException("TimeOut")
End If
```

The function I am calling is real simple:

```
Private Function myFunc(ByVal param1 As Decimal, ByRef param2 As DatabaseObject) As DataSet
        DatabaseObject= New DatabaseObjectClass

         Dim datos As DataSet = DatabaseObject.GetRegistry(param1)
         Return datos

End Function
```

Randomly, I start getting timeout emails because that task who recovers a simple DataSet from database is getting timeout (Who is configured in 50000 milliseconds and it's very weird.

Im starting to thing it could be **network related problems**, because the function fails and it is caught by an exception but the next time if executes it works nice.

I would be glad if you give me some ideas.

Comment: I hope it is not a threading issue. You may need to look into the Database.GetRegistry method, if it is the root for TimeOut exceptions..

Comment: I have a timeout in other function as well. By the way this method can't be faulty because it executes maybe a thousand times before I start getting the timeoutExceptions :/